# how to fix numbering

Tags: numbering, texmaker

I have to follow my university role. they say everything must have a right page number. the problem is two following:

Table of Contents.. v

List of Tables and List of Symbols… viii    The list need to start on a new page not a continuation from the table.  Also remove the two question marks at the end of the list of tables.

Table of Contents is more than one page (3 pages) and it goes from v,vi,1 how I can have the above format?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{unbthesis}
%\usepackage[left=4cm, right=2.5cm, top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{enumitem} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage[subfigure]{tocloft} % no number for Vita in ToC
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{footmisc}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{amssymb} 
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\usepackage{amsfonts} 
\usepackage{amsthm} 
\usepackage{longtable} 
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{qtree}
\usepackage{mathabx}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[symbols,nogroupskip,sort=none]{glossaries-extra}
\title{Outer approximations of core points for integer programming}
\author{Naghmeh Shahverdizadeh Shargh}
\predegree{Master of Science, University of Shahid Beheshti, Iran, 2013}
\degree{Doctor of Philosophy}
\gau{Mathematics and Statistics}
\supervisor{David Bremner, Ph.D, Computer Science\\ & Barry Monson, Ph.D,
Mathematics}
\examboard{Branimir Ćaćić, Ph.D, Mathematics
Chair\\  & Nicholas Touikan,  Ph.D, Mathematics}
\externalexam{Tamon Stephen, Ph.D,
Mathematics ,Simon Fraser University}
\date{January, 2021}
\copyrightyear{2021}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}

\DeclareMathOperator{\Mat}{Mat} 
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\begin{document}
\unbtitlepage
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3} \setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\pagenumbering{roman} \setcounter{page}{1}

\include{abstract}
\include{dedication}
\include{acknowledgments}

%%-----------Table of Contents------------------
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Table of Contents}
\tableofcontents{}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Table of Contents}
%%------------List of Tables----------------------
\listoftables{}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Tables}
%%------------List of Figures----------------------

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Figures}
%%-------------change single space to double space--------
\doublespacing \pagenumbering{arabic} \setcounter{page}{1}
\newcommand{\Po}{\mathcal{P}}
\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}
\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}} 
\newcommand{\C}{\mathbb{C}} 
\newcommand{\Q}{\mathbb{Q}} 
\newcommand{\F}{\mathbb{F}} 
\newcommand{\oh}{\mathcal{O}}

%

\newcommand{\Sym}{\mathrm{Sym}} 
\newcommand{\vt}{\mathrm{vert}}
\newcommand{\conv}{\mathrm{conv}}
\newcommand{\Cir}{\mathrm{Cir}}
\newcommand{\Fix}{\mathrm{Fix}}
\newcommand{\spa}{\mathrm{span}}
\newcommand{\PCir}{\mathrm{PCir}}
\newcommand{\rank}{\mathrm{rank}}
\newcommand{\core}{\mathrm{core}}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{example}[theorem]{Example}
\newtheorem{notation}[theorem]{Notation}
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{remark}[theorem]{Remark}

%\glsxtrnewsymbol[description={Euclidean inner product in}]{ \langle ., . \rangle}{\ensuremath{ \langle ., . \rangle}}
\glsxtrnewsymbol[description={all-ones vector}]{v}{\ensuremath{ \mathbf{1}}}
\glsxtrnewsymbol[description={standard (usual) basis vectors for $\mathbb{R}^n$; $e_{i} = (0,\ldots, 1, \ldots,0)$}]{Q}{\ensuremath{ e_{1},...,e_{n}}}
\glsxtrnewsymbol[description={Euclidean inner product on \ensuremath{ \R^{n}}}]{g}{\ensuremath{ \langle ., . \rangle}}
\glsxtrnewsymbol[description={set of core points of a group $  G$ that are contained in a set $ S$ (Definition \ref{subgroup})}]{3}{\ensuremath{ \core(G,S)}}
\glsxtrnewsymbol[description={convex hull of the set $S$ (Definition \ref{conv}) }]{5}{\ensuremath{\conv(S)}}
\glsxtrnewsymbol[description={convex hull of an integer point \ensuremath{z} under the action of a group  \ensuremath{G} (Definition \ref{convG}) }]{4}{\ensuremath{\conv(G_{z})}}
\glsxtrnewsymbol[description={$G$-orbit representatives of the core set of a group $ G $ (Equation \eqref{eq1})}]{6}{\ensuremath{ \mathrm{core}_/ (G)}}
\glsxtrnewsymbol[description={set of all core points of a group $ G $ (Definition \ref{convG})}]{7}{\ensuremath{ \core(G)}}
\glsxtrnewsymbol[description={cyclic group of order $ n$}]{8}{\ensuremath{ C_{n} }}
\glsxtrnewsymbol[description={circulant matrix of a point $ c$  (Definition \ref{sec:orgc32b501})}]{9}{\ensuremath{ \Cir(c)}}
\glsxtrnewsymbol[description={ fundamental core set of a group $ G $  (Definition \ref{fund})}]{10}{\ensuremath{ \text{f}\core(G)}}
\glsxtrnewsymbol[description={fixed space of a group $ G$  (Definition \ref{fixedspace})}]{11}{\ensuremath{\Fix(G)}}
\glsxtrnewsymbol[description={integral points in the fixed space of $ G$  (Definition \ref{fixedspace})}]{12}{\ensuremath{  \Fix_{\Z}(G)}}
\glsxtrnewsymbol[description={a cyclic permutation of coordinates}]{18}{\ensuremath{   \sigma}}
\glsxtrnewsymbol[description={linear hull of a set $ S$}]{13}{\ensuremath{  \spa ( S)}}
\glsxtrnewsymbol[description={affine hull of a set $ S$}]{13}{\ensuremath{ aff(S)}}
\glsxtrnewsymbol[description={the set $ \{1,...,n\} $}]{14}{\ensuremath{ $[n]$}}
\glsxtrnewsymbol[description={stabilizer of a set $ S $ in a permutation group $ G$  (Definition \ref{stabl})}]{15}{\ensuremath{\operatorname{Stab}_{G}(S) }}
\glsxtrnewsymbol[description={A finite field with dimension $ n\times m$}]{16}{\ensuremath{ \F^{n\times m}}}
\printunsrtglossary[type=symbols,style=long]
```

Comment: Is the file `unbthesis.cls` available online somewhere?

Comment: I found it at this [link](https://www.unb.ca/etd/_resources/templates/latex/unb-thesis_latex-template.zip)

Answer (score 1):

You have to put the `\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Table of Contents}` before the
`\tableofcontents{}`, and the same for the others.
And if you want the List of Tables to start on a new page, insert `\newpage` before it, same for the others. The `\newpage` must be before the `\addcontentsline`. And there must be a `\newpage` before changing the `\pagenumbering`.

Something like this

```
%%-----------Table of Contents------------------
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Table of Contents}
\newpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Table of Contents}
\tableofcontents{}
%%------------List of Tables----------------------
\newpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Tables}
\listoftables{}
%%------------List of Figures----------------------
\newpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Figures}
\listoffigures{}
\newpage
%%-------------change single space to double space--------
```